# Postgresql query not use index with or condition

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following query.

```
select * 
  from (select p.*, (select 1
                       from alarmitems a
                      where (a.pair = p.pair OR a.pair = 'ALL')
                        and (a.buy = p.buy OR a.buy = 'ALL')
                        and (a.sell = p.sell OR a.sell = 'ALL')
                        and a.percentage < p.percentage
                     ) as alarmpriority
          from pairpercentages p
         where not exists (select 1
                             from filtereditems f
                            where (p.pair = f.pair OR f.pair = 'ALL') 
                                  AND 
                                  (p.buy = f.buy OR f.buy = 'ALL') 
                                  AND
                                  (p.sell = f.sell OR f.sell = 'ALL')    
                                  AND 
                                  (p.percentage < f.percentage)
                                  AND
                                  ((f.contractaddress = '' OR f.contractaddress = 'ALL') 
                                    OR
                                   (f.contractaddress = p.buycontractaddress)
                                    OR
                                   (f.contractaddress = p.sellcontractaddress))
                           )
           and not exists (select *
                             from alarmitems a
                            where (a.pair = p.pair OR a.pair = 'ALL')
                              and (a.buy = p.buy OR a.buy = 'ALL')
                              and (a.sell = p.sell OR a.sell = 'ALL')
                              and a.percentage > p.percentage
                          )
       )x
```

When I look at the execution plan, I see that the cost is high. I also see it as not using the indexes I put in the buy, sell, pair and contractaddress fields. How can I rearrange the query for better performance?

The execution plan is as follows;

```
Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.28..309011.51 rows=22 width=180)
  Join Filter: ((p.percentage < f.percentage) AND ((p.pair = f.pair) OR (f.pair = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((p.buy = f.buy) OR (f.buy = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((p.sell = f.sell) OR (f.sell = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((f.contractaddress = ''::text) OR (f.contractaddress = 'ALL'::text) OR (f.contractaddress = p.buycontractaddress) OR (f.contractaddress = p.sellcontractaddress)))
  ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.28..306617.96 rows=29 width=176)
        Join Filter: ((a.percentage > p.percentage) AND ((a.pair = p.pair) OR (a.pair = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((a.buy = p.buy) OR (a.buy = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((a.sell = p.sell) OR (a.sell = 'ALL'::text)))
        ->  Index Scan Backward using idx_percentage on pairpercentages p  (cost=0.28..305488.43 rows=36 width=176)
              Filter: ((((SubPlan 2) IS NULL) AND (percentage > '0'::double precision)) OR ((SubPlan 3) = 1))
              SubPlan 2
                ->  Seq Scan on alarmitems a_2  (cost=0.00..41.10 rows=1 width=4)
                      Filter: ((percentage < p.percentage) AND ((pair = p.pair) OR (pair = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((buy = p.buy) OR (buy = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((sell = p.sell) OR (sell = 'ALL'::text)))
              SubPlan 3
                ->  Seq Scan on alarmitems a_3  (cost=0.00..41.10 rows=1 width=4)
                      Filter: ((percentage < p.percentage) AND ((pair = p.pair) OR (pair = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((buy = p.buy) OR (buy = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((sell = p.sell) OR (sell = 'ALL'::text)))
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..28.33 rows=1022 width=29)
              ->  Seq Scan on alarmitems a  (cost=0.00..23.22 rows=1022 width=29)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..87.34 rows=1223 width=60)
        ->  Seq Scan on filtereditems f  (cost=0.00..81.23 rows=1223 width=60)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on alarmitems a_1  (cost=0.00..41.10 rows=1 width=4)
          Filter: ((percentage < p.percentage) AND ((pair = p.pair) OR (pair = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((buy = p.buy) OR (buy = 'ALL'::text)) AND ((sell = p.sell) OR (sell = 'ALL'::text)))
JIT:
  Functions: 43
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Comment: [Avoid the `OR`](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/) and never post execution plans as screenshots.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show the original **text** output of `explain (analyze, buffers) select ...`  as formatted text (the way you formatted your SQL code). The screenshot is hiding too many details and it seems it's also the result of a simple `explain` rather than `explain (analyze)`

Comment: Sorry. I added execution plan details as text.